# AnnotatorJS - Necessery fields for retrieving previously stored annotations

Tags: javascript, annotations

I am using AnnotatorJS library, and I want to retrieve previously stored annotations from database.
My JSON looks like :

```
[{"id":null,"text":"content text","tags":["food","summer"],"tagsStr":null,"ranges":[{"start":"/p[1]","end":"/p[1]","startOffset":82,"endOffset":88}],"json":null}]
```

There are some additional properties, and most of original ones are excluded.

Could someone experienced with this library tell me what would be a minimal set of attributes needed for displaying previously stored annotations?
Should the retrieved objects be "as is"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimal set is: id (so the library could determine is it update or create)
and ranges.
The problem was with id - it was null, so when you're using this library, make sure id is not null (previosly explained why)
Big thanks to the annotator crew!